# WMSAuth implementation

Tags: c#, strings, datetime, cryptography

I have to implement WMSAuth in C#: http://wmsauth.org/examples

```
// The following function was copied from http://wmsauth.org/examples
public static string BuildProtectedURLWithValidity(string password, string media_url, string ip, int valid)
{
    string result = null;
    DateTime cur_date = DateTime.Now;
    TimeZone localzone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

    DateTime localTime = localzone.ToUniversalTime(cur_date);

    string date_time = localTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-us"));

    Int32 Valid = valid;
    string to_be_hashed = ip + password + date_time + Valid.ToString();

    byte[] to_be_hashed_byte_array = new byte[to_be_hashed.Length];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (char cur_char in to_be_hashed)
    {
        to_be_hashed_byte_array[i++] = (byte)cur_char;
    }

    byte[] hash = (new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(to_be_hashed_byte_array);

    string md5_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

    result = media_url + "?server_time=" + date_time + "&hash_value=" + md5_signature + "&validminutes=" + Valid.ToString();
    return (result);
}
```

The problem is that, although I believe the code above might work for every possible input, it seems to be done without much knowledge of C#, and I have a big concern with the [Encoding in the byte to char casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708548/encoding-used-in-cast-from-char-to-byte).

So I changed the code to this:

```
private static string BuildProtectedURLWithValidity(string wmsAuthPassword, string mediaUrl, string clientIp, int validMinutes)
{
    string dateTimeString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-us"));
    string validMinutesString = validMinutes.ToString();

    string stringToBeHashed = clientIp + wmsAuthPassword + dateTimeString + validMinutesString;
    string hashValue;
    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] bytesToBeHashed = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToBeHashed);
        byte[] hashBytes = md5Provider.ComputeHash(bytesToBeHashed);
        hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    }

    string result = mediaUrl + "?server_time=" + dateTimeString + "&hash_value=" + hashValue + "&validminutes=" + validMinutesString;
    return result;
}
```

But my real concern is that with my attempt to follow the company's naming standards and improve the code readability I might be introducing a bug in already tested code. Would you use the version posted in the the WMSAuth page?

Note: It has to work with the .NET Framework 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that the example code provided effectively does a `% 256` on the input characters. So it's possible that your version and the example code yield two different values for the same input.

However you said *I believe the code above might work for every possible input* - I take it then that `password` will never contain any characters where the wrap-around will play a role? If that's the case then your version should be equivalent.

If you are paranoid then replace `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` in your code with the same loop as used in the example but leave your other refactorings intact.

In fact I would refactor the `result` into:

```
string.Format("{0}?server_time={1}&hash_value={2}&validminutes={3}", mediaUrl, dateTimeString, hashValue, validMinutes);
```

Which means you could also get rid of the `validMinutesString`.